# How to add multiple values for a struct in c using pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I don't know how to add multiple values for a struct in C using a pointer. Here's my code and the gcc error is:

> error: assignment to expression with array type  `(p+0)->name = "Teszt";`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[101];
    int born_in;
} paciens;

int main(){
    paciens *p;
    int n = 5;
    p = (paciens*) malloc(n * sizeof(paciens));

    (p+0)->name = "Test";
    (p+0)->born_in = 1992;

    printf("Name: %s ; Born in: %d\n", (p+0)->name, (p+0)->born_in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(p+0)->name = "Test";` ==> `strcpy((p+0)->name, "Test");`

Comment: The section in your reference text/site on how to copy strings in C would be a good place to start (or any of the *thousands* of hits google will return on the same subject).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array, but you can assign to a `struct`, which contains an array:

```
p[0] = (paciens) { .name = "Test", .born_in = 1992};
```

will do this. This is called a compound literal.

https://ideone.com/f99rUF

Also note that you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The member `name` is an array. You can't assign to an array, only copy to it. To copy a string use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

```
strcpy(p[0].name, "Test");
```

Any good book, tutorial or teacher should have mentioned this.

Comment: Any other method where we dont use <string.h> library?

Comment: @32icHARD Well `char` strings in C are really called *null-terminated byte strings*. It's easy to implement your own variant of `strcpy` with a simple loop if you remember the proper name. But I fail to see why anyone would want that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, have a nice day! :)